# PHP Interfacing with Python -- Getting Null Return Value

Tags: php, python

I lifted some code off of StackOverflow to test some very basic PHP / Python integration, as I would like to eventually create a web interface for a Python machine learning platform I've been testing for a while now.

The code is as follows below:

PHP:

```
<?php

    $data = array('1', '2', '3');
    $result = shell_exec('python "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache24\htdocs\Machine-Learning-Python-Integration\phptransfertest.py" ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)));

    $resultData = json_decode($result, true);

    var_dump($resultData);

?>
```

Python:

```
import sys
import json

try:
    data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])

except:
    print "ERROR"
    sys.exit(1)

result = {'status': 'Yes!'}

print json.dumps(result)
```

But when I load this up in a browser, it only outputs NULL. I am unsure how to properly pass variables and files between Python and PHP, and most guides I have found tend to give me a NULL error.

Comment: If you follow guides for 100% and they give you a NULL error, perhaps your php is not set up correctly. If you did not follow them, but applied them to your problem, look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php `shell_exec` is supposed to return NULL if something goes wrong with executing the command. What kind of string does  `. escapeshellarg(json_encode($data))` create? Does this info help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197815/how-to-pass-variable-from-php-to-python

Comment: How did you solve this ? I'm coming across the same issue and have tried everything by now.