# Passing php variable to python script and vise versa on Windows

Tags: php, python, shell-exec

I want to pass a php variable to python script and then use it for execution in pyhton. Then I want to pass the result of the python script back to php file

Tried this :

test.php

```
<?php
   $param = 6;
   $result= shell_exec("python C:/xampp/htdocs/test/script.py $param");
   echo $result;
?>
```

and the python script

script.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

x = sys.argv[1]
print (x)
r = x + 5

print (r)
```

I'm getting a blank screen when I try to run test.php on browser meaning the variables are not being passed.
I want to use the results from python script in php for further calculations.

I'm running both the codes on Windows interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variable from PHP to Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197815/how-to-pass-variable-from-php-to-python)

Comment: @xskxzr tried that, it's not working. Also I need to pass the variable value back to the php from python. Any other solutions?

Comment: Same issue here. How did you solve this ? I've solved almost everything.