# Send variable's from PHP to Python?

Tags: python, php, variables

I found a way to get only one variable, And I need 18

I am currently using the code

```
echo shell_exec("C:/Python/python.exe C:/wamp64/www/site/test.py 2>&1");
```

**The code Works great but how do I send variables to python?**

Comment: If I Google your question I get this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197815/how-can-i-pass-variable-from-php-to-python What did you try so far, I think this question is asked already many times

Comment: I tried but it does not work for me with two variables

Comment: why dont you insert 1 variabe as json string and decode it in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just pass them as command line arguments:

`exec ( "C:/Python/python.exe C:/wamp64/www/site/test.py $var1 $var2 $var3" );`

Then in your Python script you can read them like this:

```
import sys

print sys.argv[1] # first parameter
print sys.argv[2] # second parameter
print sys.argv[3] # third parameter
```